Debugging Rosetta2 Binary with VSCode
i have a cpp application built in a docker container based on
--platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/cpp:0-ubuntu-22.04
I am running that container on Apple Silicon. The build process is no problem, but when i want to debug my application, i got stuck.
I already tried to set breakpoints and debug by hand following this short instructions,
but now i want to translate that to a launch.json file using a prelaunch-task to start the rosetta binary and after that attaching gdb debugger to localhost:1234.
I tried around a bit with starting the debugserver manual and attaching the debugger to it by launch.json. At the end this lead to nothing and is not worth mentioning it.
